# I am unable to save data with configparser

Tags: python, configparser

I'm trying to save some data with config parser but I keep on getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    if config['settings']['a setting']:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'settings'`
```

Here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
import configparser

config=configparser.ConfigParser()

def settings():
    config['settings']={}
    config['settings']['a setting']=input('type:')
    with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
      config.write(configfile)

if input('Enter Settings?')=="Yes":
   settings()

if config['settings']['a setting']:
    print(config['settings']['a setting'])
```

It only shows the error when I do not run `settings()`, but it will work if I do.

Comment: Because if you don't call the `settings()` *function*, there is no `'settings'` *section* in which to store values.

Answer (score 1):

The KeyError occurs because the 'settings' key is only defined in the ConfigParser object (which is an extension of dict), if you enter "Yes" to the first input prompt.

You could partially solve this by always creating the ['settings'] section  before that prompt.

```
if not config.has_section('settings'):
    config.add_section('settings')
```

But you can also use better guards around the issue by checking that the sections or options exist before referencing them, or by using the ConfigParser.get() method.

Some possible options:

1. Use the ConfigParser.get() method:
   This is similar to the dict.get() method, but the parameters passed in are `get(section, option, *, raw=False, vars=None[, fallback])`

> Get an option value for the named section. If vars is provided, it
> must be a dictionary. The option is looked up in vars (if provided),
> section, and in DEFAULTSECT in that order. If the key is not found and
> fallback is provided, it is used as a fallback value. None can be
> provided as a fallback value.

Since you have no existing file, and haven't created a DEFAULT section yet,  its going to end up going to the fallback, and the ConfigParser version of get() does not automatically use None as dict.get() does.

Example: `print(config.get('settings', 'a setting', fallback=None))`

2. Get the section, and then you can is as a dict(). Such as:

```
if config.has_section('settings'):
    section = config['settings']
    for option, value in section.items():
        print(f"{option} = {value}")
```

Alternatively, if you just want to reference the ConfigParser object:

```
section = 'settings'
if config.has_section(section):
    for option in config.options(section):
        print(f"{option} = {config.get(section, option)}")
```

You may also want to look into the ConfigParser docs for the read_dict and read_string methods for settings up initial settings if you don't already have the .ini to read from.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Your code gives me this error..
`TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'option'` 
@nigh_anxiety

Comment: I had to dig into the configparser docs a bit more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html. It appears that at the ConfigParser level, the .get function is a bit different. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updates done.  I didn't do a full rewrite of your sample code as it seemed to be mostly just practice with ConfigParser at this point and not planned end code.